# What is the difference between these addressing modes...?

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode

What is the difference between a register, indirect, base+displacement, double indirect, and PC relative.  I'm not quite sure I understand how to differentiate between these different addressing modes given their use in some situation.  Can someone please help me recognize the difference between them?

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) on that topic is pretty extensive, you should take a look!

Comment: Please clarify your question.  The fact that you mention a rather extensive list of addressing modes may hint at the fact that you do not understand the _purpose_ of addressing itself.  As you may know, addressing modes are merely conventions that define the specific set of operations that will be used to compute the effective address [of some action such as reading, writing, comparing etc.].  Therefore one may get confused by the specific "mechanical" computations related to a particular mode,  or maybe one may be wondering which particular use case would make a given mode useful, or maybe...

Comment: (cont.) ... one may wonder about performance considerations, but asking for "difference between these [relatively unrelated] addressing modes" is a rather open question.

Comment: I'm simply asking for syntactical differences, and I'm not particularly interested in *how* they operate.  I know this may sound confusing, but I just want to know, shown some instruction, how one can determine which of the above addressing modes it represents.

Comment: Response will also vary for different CPUs (and indeed different assemblers, as some conventions can be assembler-specific).  Which CPU family are you using?  x86?

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, at the level of the assembly code, the addressing mode is determined by multiple factors...

- the OP code used (e.g. some operations use implicitly specific registers or addressing modes)
- the operands: are these references to registers, to memory or immediate values
- some directives such as the byte directives as in `MOV DWORD PTR ...`

The operand(s), and the syntax that surrounds them, however are typically the most relevant with regards to determining the addressing mode.  This can be illustrated with the x86 MOV operation, as the same or very similar syntax applies to other operations on CPUs in the x86 family. Similar syntax and rules apply to other processors, but of course differences in architecture such as the list and roles of registers as well as other differences make the following relatively x86-specific.
`MOV` has the effect of copying the data referenced by its 2nd argument into the location referred by its first argument.  There are many possible combination with regard to the nature of these references:

```
MOV <reg>, <reg>      ;  register to register
MOV <reg>, <mem>      ;  memory to register
MOV <mem>, <reg>      ;  register to memory
MOV <reg>, <const>    ;  immediate value to register
MOV <mem>, <const>    ;  immediate value to memory
```

Furthermore, these references may be indirect when the corresponding operand is in brackets.  For example  `MOV WORD PTR [ebx], 99`  will move the value 99 expressed as a 16 bits integer, into the memory location pointed to by the EBX register.

Also, the indirect memory location in bracket may be expressed as a *simple* arithmetic expression such as `MOV [esi+eax], dl`.  Here the byte in register DL is copied to the memory location found by adding the contents of ESI and EAX registers.  Note that this needn't be just two registers, it could also be expressions like `[esi + 8*ebx]` or `[esi - 16]` etc.

With all that in mind, here a few examples of the MOV operation in context:

```
MOV eax, [edx]   ; Copies 4 bytes in memory at the address contained in EDX 
                 ; into EAX the size (4bytes) is implied by the size of EAX.

MOV [MyVar], ebx ; Copies the contents of EBX into the 4 bytes at memory address
                 ; MyVar. (Assumes MyVar is a 32-bit constant).

MOV eax, [esi-4] ; Copies 4 bytes at memory address ESI -4 into EAX

MOV [esi+eax], bl ; Copies the contents of BL (one byte) into the byte at address
                  ; ESI+EAX

MOV BYTE PTR [MyVar], 123 ;  Copies the (decimal) value 123 coded as an 8 bits
                          ; to the memory address contained by MyVar.
                          ; Here the size directive (BYTE PTR) is necessary.
```